# How to change keyboard layout for all users in CentOS 7 Mate?

Tags: linux, keyboard, centos, keyboard-layout

I need to set russian as default language and English as secondary language for all users in my system (CentOS 7, Mate). I've tried to google it and found that **localectl** might help me, but it was unsuccessfully:

```
# localectl set-x11-keymap ru,us
# localectl set-keymap ru,us
```

And then from user:

```
$ localectl
System Locale: LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
   VC Keymap: ru,us
  X11 Layout: ru,us
$ setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us
```

And there is only en layout in user session.

P.S.: It's not so important cause it don't affect all users but then I've tried to run in user session:

```
$setxkbmap -layout ru,us
```

And I still don't see switching keyboard layouts, but if I set this settings in Settings -> Hardware -> Keyboard then and only then I have two keyboard layouts in user session.

P.P.S.: And finally my **/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-keyboard.conf** file:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "system-keyboard"
    MatchIsKeyboard "on"
    Option "XkbLayout" "ru,us"
EndSection
```

I found that all user's dconf settings are in /home/$USER/.config/dconf/user but it's a binary file so I can't take something useful from it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Found another methon but it doesn't work for me too: http://askubuntu.com/questions/604462/how-to-set-languages-shortcuts-from-config-files-or-command-line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create file **/etc/dconf/db/local.d/01-set-layouts**:

```
[org/mate/desktop/peripherals/keyboard/kbd]

layouts=['ru','us']
options=['grp\tgrp:ctrl_shift_toggle']

[org/mate/desktop/peripherals/keyboard/general]

default-group=0
```

Run as root:

```
# dconf update
```

And then all new users will have **russian** layout by default. This does not affect those existing users who already have configured keyboard layout.

Hope that it will be useful for somebody :)